# Azure blob GET request authorization header "x-ms-date" field issue

Tags: azure, get, postman, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to fetch a html page which is placed in Azure blob storage using postman. The default blob storage access has been set to private, so i have to send "Shared Key", "x-ms-version" and "x-ms-date" in the header section to Authorize.

Here is the screen shot of request in Postman.

[image]

When i click on send button i am getting an error stating "The date header in the request is incorrect".

[image]

Any ideas to solve the issue?

**Update-Corrected Date Format**

I corrected the "x-ms-date" format, now it throwing an error stating Authentication Info is not in correct format

[image]

Here is the Authorization section of postman

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How are you computing authorization header value?

Comment: I am following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key instructions...and for generating shared key Azure Portal> Home>MyStorageAccount>Account share access Signature > Generate SAS snd connection String

Comment: It looks like you haven't acquired your token. The "SharedKey myaccount:ctzMq410TV3wS7upTBcunJTDLEJwMAZuFPfr0mrrA08=  " Needs to go in the Authorization tab in Postman. Not the Header tab.

Comment: @Rthomas529 but documentation mentioned to pass Authorization as header..if you want me to try that on Authorization tab , please let me know which Authorization type to select

Comment: It's literally telling you that the Authorization is in the incorrect format. This is because "SharedKey account:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" is not the correct format.

Comment: You don't use ```"SharedKey account"```  It should be something like ```"SharedKey {{storageAccountName}}:{{signedSignature}}``` Also for security reasons your key should be hashed.

Comment: Looks like author's date is in good format. The remaining thing is the Authorization header. The thing I found out is that this is not the key on Azure Portal. It's way more complicated than that. Here is [a doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-rest-api-auth#creating-the-authorization-header) that explains a bit about it.

Answer (score 5):

Please review the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key).

You need to specify two headers for correct request: `Authorization` and `x-ms-date` headers.

The correct format for `x-ms-date` header is `Fri, 26 Jun 2015 23:39:12 GMT`.

It seems your `Authorization` header is invalid.
Try to regenerate your SAS key and test your request again.

As I understand correctly then you have only 15 minutes for requests.

From documentation:

> The storage services ensure that a request is no older than 15 minutes by the time it reaches the service. This guards against certain security attacks, including replay attacks. When this check fails, the server returns response code 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: The 15 minute duration is maximum duration allowed between request initiation at client( taken from x-ms-date to request process at server. This 15minute cut off helps microsoft to avoid Replay attacks(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack)

Answer (score 3):

The format is `Fri, 26 Jun 2015 23:39:12 GMT`. In Python, this can be obtained via

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
```

assuming `locale.en_US`.

Answer (score 1):

x-ms-date header must be specified in the following format: Fri, 26 Jun 2015 23:39:12 GMT.

Please try your request again with this format.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the format that I used for UTC was wrong.
I changed to `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R")`. previously it was

```
((DateTime.UtcNow).ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss ") + "GMT" ))
```